# how to make the Kendo responsive

Tags: jquery, arrays, kendo-ui, resize

I am new to Jquery. I would appreciate any comment.

I would like to integrate windows size in KENDO Wizard in Jquery.
I would like to bind the **contentPosition** value based on windows size.
However, it does not return the correct value.
How to return the String value and bind the right place?
Thanks in advance.

```
   var navValue = "";
    $(window).resize(function() { 
        if($(window).width() > 768) 
         {   
            return navValue ="right";  
         }   
    });

    $("#wizard").kendoWizard({
        pager: true, 
        contentPosition : navValue.toString()  , //default "bottom" // I would like to bind this value form the function

        done: function (e) {
            e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
            kendo.alert("Thank you for registering! Registration details will be sent to your email.");
        },
        steps: [
            {
                title: "Account Details",
                buttons: ["next"],
                form: {
                    orientation: "vertical",
                    formData: { 
                     .........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm deducing that your actual question is "how to make the Kendo Wizard responsive". I'm guessing that when the window is resized, you'll want the stepper at the left side when the window width is greater than 768.

Tried a couple of things. First, manipulating the wizard CSS nearly works but the not quite. Tried `setOptions` but it had no effect. So I ended up destroying and recreating the wizard widget on window resize. Try the code below in the Telerik Dojo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.224/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.224/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="wizard"></div>

<script>
    var $wizard = $("#wizard");
    var wizard = $wizard.kendoWizard({
        contentPosition: "right",
        steps: ["Initial step", "Second step", "Third step"]
    }).data('kendoWizard');
    
    $(window).resize(function() { 
        if($(window).width() > 768) {       
            if (wizard.options.contentPosition != "right") {
                var options = wizard.options;
                var step = 0;
                var steps = options.stepper.steps;
                for (let i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
                    var step = steps[i];
                    if (step.selected) {
                        step = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                options.contentPosition = "right";
                wizard.destroy();
                $wizard.empty();
                $wizard.removeAttr('class');
                $wizard.removeAttr('data-role');
                $wizard.removeAttr('role');
                
                wizard = $wizard.kendoWizard(options).data('kendoWizard');
                wizard.select(step);
            }
        } else {            
            if (wizard.options.contentPosition != "bottom") {
                var options = wizard.options;
                var step = 0;
                var steps = options.stepper.steps;
                for (let i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
                    var step = steps[i];
                    if (step.selected) {
                        step = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                options.contentPosition = "bottom";
                wizard.destroy();
                $wizard.empty();
                $wizard.removeAttr('class');
                $wizard.removeAttr('data-role');
                $wizard.removeAttr('role');
                
                wizard = $wizard.kendoWizard(options).data('kendoWizard');
                wizard.select(step);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes!. I should change the title  "how to make the Kendo Wizard responsive". Actually, this is what I exactly want. Even though the code seems hard for me but, I am going to take a look at your answer to understand!. 
I really appreciate your answer. :)